# Proper way to perform division in java

Tags: java, android, integer

Ok, I have searched high and low for this and come back scratching my head... I am used to php and new to java so please be patient with me...

I am building an app that does some basic math(personal app, not marketing it) that I will use on a daily basis. The app install fine and runs but when I hit the calculate button I get 0 as the answer. What am i doing wrong?

```
float val1 = Integer.parseInt(fat.getText().toString()) *1;
float vals1 = (int) 3.89;
float val2 = Integer.parseInt(carbs.getText().toString()) *1;
float vals2 = (int) 9.17;
float val3 = Integer.parseInt(fiber.getText().toString()) *1;  
float vals3 = (int) 12.49;
float val4= Integer.parseInt(protein.getText().toString()) *1; 
float vals4 = (int) 10.94;
float answer = (float) (((val4 / vals4) + (val2 / vals2) + (val1 / vals1)) - (val3 / vals3));  
Integer answerf = (int) answer;
points.setText(answerf.toString());
```

Edit:
as requested the expected values(for a test run)

```
val1 = 7
val2 = 26
val3 = 2
val4 = 5
```

expected outcome is 5

Comment: please post the values of your EditTexts

Comment: Why are you casting the floats to int? You can make float values by appending "f" to the number.

Comment: Almost all your castings don't really make sense...

Comment: I don't know what the "*1" factors buy you. Why not use ParseFloat()? Why are you truncating your valsX values to int?

Comment: Was unintentional. I was working on this sporadically throughout the past few days and wasn't keeping my normal level of notes. Probable a mis-conversion from one attempt to another to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end result might just be caused by loss in precisions due to all that type castings that you might unintentionally did.

When you cast a double or float value to an int and then back to float, you lose a lot of precisions. You should keep the variable types consistent until the last step where you really want or need to convert calculated value from one type to another.

You also do not need to multiply by 1 (*1), since it doesn't do anything to the result of integer multiplication.

If you need to round things of use Math.round() instead of casting float to integer.

Your code, depending on what you intend to do, should look more like:

```
float val1 = Float.parseFloat(fat.getText().toString());
float vals1 = 3.89f;
float val2 = Float.parseFloat(carbs.getText().toString());
float vals2 = 9.17f;
float val3 = Float.parseFloat(fiber.getText().toString()); 
float vals3 = 12.49f;
float val4= Float.parseFloat(protein.getText().toString());
float vals4 = 10.94f;
float answer = (((val4 / vals4) + (val2 / vals2) + (val1 / vals1)) - (val3 / vals3));
points.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(answer)));
```

Comment: typo on my part made it show a 0... like i said, new to java, thank you all so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Check if your **EditTexts** contain valid Numbers, and do it like that:
In this example I assume that the EditText contains the value "10".

```
    float val1 = Integer.parseInt("10") *1;
    float vals1 =  3.89f;
    float val2 = Integer.parseInt("10") *1;
    float vals2 = 9.17f;
    float val3 = Integer.parseInt("10") *1;  
    float vals3 =  12.49f;
    float val4= Integer.parseInt("10") *1; 
    float vals4 =  10.94f;
    float answer = (float) (((val4 / vals4) + (val2 / vals2) + (val1 / vals1)) - (val3 / vals3));  

    System.out.println("Result: " + answer);
```

The result here is: 3.7746425

> Furthermore, it does not make any sense to cast your double values to
>   int to be able to assign them to float.

Answer (score 0):

Several things wrong. First of all, you're using `Integer.parseInt()` but you're tryign to parse a float. You should use `Float.parseFloat()` or `Double.parseDouble()`.

Also,

```
float vals1 = (int) 3.89;
```

doesn't really make sense. You're removing the decimal portion by converting a double literal to an int, but still storing it in a float. Remove the cast, and change `3.89` to `3.89F` to signify it is a float.

Because as of right now, in the end this line:

```
float answer = (float) (((val4 / vals4) + (val2 / vals2) + (val1 / vals1)) - (val3 / vals3));
```

Is doing a bunch of mathematical operations on an int, which will return an `int`, but then you're casting it to a `float`. So it'll be a `float`, but have an `int` value.

Comment: Also the `*1` at the end of each typecasting don't really make sense

Comment: Ok so I changed it, removed the cast and added the f to it. Ultimately  I am seeking to calculate as a float and then round up to the next level, so at this point am I right in assuming that casting the result to in int is the wrong thing to do?

Comment: You can calculate your result as a float by merely performing all your operations on floating type variables. Then you should use the Math.round() method to round your float to an int if that's what you need.